# Defining an abstract Lie group

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Whenever the group $SU(N)$ is presented, it is usually given as
\begin{equation}
SU(N)=\{U\in GL(N,\mathbb{C})| UU^\dagger=1, \text{det}(U)=1\}.
\end{equation}
However, it seems to me that this is really the definition of the **fundamental representation** of $SU(N)$. So if I were to ask myself how to give a definition of the **abstract** $SU(N)$ group, my tendency would be to instead start from the algebra, and say that an element of the **abstract** $SU(N)$ group is obtained through the exponential map from an arbitrary linear combination of the Lie algebra elements. The Lie algebra is abstractly defined by its commutation relation, and so everything is nice and well behaved.

This cannot be done, however, if the group is not connected, for example, as the exponential map allows only to reach the elements of the component that contains the identity element. So in this case, to define an **abstract** Lie group, I would have to know its Lie algebra **and** the center of the group or its topology.

My question, in short, is: how do we define abstract Lie groups in practical cases, and in a way that does not hold for simple groups only? I hope the question makes sense.

Comment: I understand that this might be controversial, but defining SU(N) "in the abstract" as the set of orientation and norm preserving linear transformations in $\mathbb{C}^n$ seems abstract enough for most purposes, and for most practical cases you get the fundamental rep. once you declare the standard basis be canonical.

Exceptional Lie groups are the interesting case, so I hope someone answers the question.

I suspect once you declare the center of your group you can overcome the problem of components for matrix Lie groups! Add conjugacy classes, simply!

Comment: At least in the semisimple case, the adjoint (centreless) Lie group is the *automorphism group* of its Lie algebra, $G_{ad} =Aut(\mathfrak g)$. The simply connected Lie group is its universal cover, $G_{sc} = \tilde{G_{ad}}$. Everything else that is connected lies in between, and the quotient can also be read off the Lie algebra, as its weight lattice modulo root lattice.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg I think the adjoint group is the connected component of the identity inside $\mathrm{Aut}(\mathfrak{g})$ rather than the whole group

Comment: Right of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I would note is that a representation is not the same as a matrix representation. We don't need to choose a basis for a representation. So in your example we could say a little more abstractly that $SU(n)$ is the set of linear transformations preserving a (complex) inner product on $\mathbb{C}^n$

It is very normal to define a Lie group by one of its representations in this way and indeed in maths we usually call these the "defining representations". Note physicists call these the fundamental representations but in maths that refers to a broader group of representations.

If we want to get a more abstract definition we can use the Lie algebra but we have to be careful. There isn't **one** exponential map for a given Lie algebra. For every Lie group $G$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ there is an exponential map $\mathfrak{g}\to G$. We have to define $G$ already to get this map so we cannot use this as a definition of $G$.

As Torsten points out however we can find all the connected Lie groups with a given Lie algebra in a more abstract way. There is a unique (up to isomorphism) connected, simply-connected Lie group $\tilde{G}$ with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. All other connected Lie groups with Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ are quotients of $\tilde{G}$ by discrete subgroups of its centre. If $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple this centre itself is discrete so we can classify the groups easily.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which seems to summarise a bit of everything that was said here. I'll wait a couple days to see if anyone else wants to add on this and then give the best answer.

Comment: One thing I want to note on your second paragraph, it reminded me a quote from Weyl "The only example of a multi-dimensional representation which we offer is the following trivial one. [...] We have in fact to do the following: we first obtain the structure of a group by abstraction from the group of linear transformation and then return to the original realization by means of the correspondence between an element of the abstract group on the one hand and the linear transformation on the other."

Answer (score 3):

You're right. Different Lie groups can have the same Lie algebra, so the Lie algebra is not enough.

You asked how to define abstract Lie groups in practical cases. Different people will have different opinions of what practical means. People in engineering disciples will think a matrix parameterization is the most practical thing out there. There is also the [Adjoint representation of a Lie group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation#Definition), which might be what you're looking for.

Comment: I guess what I'm asking is how do we define an abstract Lie group without any reference to a representation of it. I could define an abstract $SU(N)$ group simply as a group that is homeomorphic to the group $SU(N)=\{U\in GL(N,\mathbb{C})| UU^\dagger=1, \ \text{det}U=1\}$. But I was wondering if there is a way to define a Lie group abstractly without referring to a representation of it.

Comment: @Tanatofobico Ah I see. That's a good question and I guess I don't really have a good answer for you. 
The definition of a manifold requires to have a set. This set can be a set of functions, a set of vectors, etc. However, you will still get the same "essence" of a manifold. No matter what, you will have a parameterization in some $\mathbb{R}^m$. I mean, I could define $SO3$ to be the set of all rotations in 3D space, but idk if you consider that a representation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was thinking the same, that since the Lie group is a manifold, then you sort of need a parametrisation to define it, which is difficult to provide "in abstract". That's why I was going for the Lie algebra and the center. The Lie algebra is defined by its commutation relations which are algebraic and do not depend on the dimension of the space on which the group acts. Thus this definition would not depend on the vector space that the group elements act on, but only on the algebraic properties of the algebra and the center.

Comment: @Tanatofobico this might not be what you’re looking for but check out diffeological spaces. They are a generalization of a manifold, they include “smooth spaces” beyond the class of manifolds. When restricted to just manifolds, I believe every manifold will have a unique diffeology attached to it. I could be wrong on that so please verify it. It’s definitely more abstract than the parameterization definition, though it is an equivalent definition! It sorta defines manifolds the same way we define topological spaces.

Comment: @Tanatofobico this is a good question. Maybe there’s a way to say “take the set of all manifolds isomorphic to this specific manifold” and that’s a more abstract way? Not perfect ofc but it’s an idea

Comment: I'll definitely check it out :). This discussion already helped me a lot, thank you!